# Junit5 annotated functions not executing with Ktor and Gardle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, junit, junit5, ktor

I am using Ktor 2.3.3, Kotlin 1.9.10 and Junit 5.10.0 with java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18

I'm trying to get a server started and then execute a series of tests against it. Here's my test code:

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import kotlin.test.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import io.ktor.server.engine.connector
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach
import io.ktor.server.config.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

class ApplicationTest {
    private lateinit var client: HttpClient

    companion object {
        val engine = TestApplicationEngine(createTestEnvironment {
            config = HoconApplicationConfig(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
        })

        @BeforeAll 
        @JvmStatic
        fun setup() {
            println("TESTING IS READY TO BEGIN!")
            engine.start(wait = false)
            engine.application.module()
        }
    }

    @BeforeEach
    fun init() {
        println("BeforeEach Initialising HttpClient!")
        client = HttpClient()
    }

    @AfterEach
    fun cleanup() {
         println("AfterEach closing client!")
        client.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun testRoot() = with(engine) {
        println("TEST CALLED!")
        with(handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/")) {
            assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, this.response.status())
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew clean test --info` I can see setup function being called but none of the other annotated functions execute. The log file indicates a server is started on `http://0.0.0.0:8070` but there are no log messages indicating the test was run and the server remains running until it is shutdown.

```
2023-10-10 22:35:41.874 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Configuring application...
2023-10-10 22:35:41.886 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Configuring logger...
2023-10-10 22:35:41.893 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Running database migration: false
2023-10-10 22:35:41.893 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Configuring HTTP...
2023-10-10 22:35:41.977 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Configuring security...
2023-10-10 22:35:41.979 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Configuring response...
2023-10-10 22:35:41.998 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Configuring routes...
2023-10-10 22:35:42.007 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Authentication successful for route: api/v2/xxxx
2023-10-10 22:35:42.007 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Routing to: api/v2/xxxx
2023-10-10 22:35:42.007 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Application started.
2023-10-10 22:35:42.007 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Application started in 0.135 seconds.
2023-10-10 22:35:42.007 [Test worker] INFO  ktor.application - Application started: io.ktor.server.application.Application@62a68bcb
2023-10-10 22:35:42.078 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#2] INFO  ktor.application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8070
2023-10-10 22:35:48.965 [KtorShutdownHook] INFO  ktor.application - Application stopping: io.ktor.server.application.Application@62a68bcb
2023-10-10 22:35:48.969 [KtorShutdownHook] INFO  ktor.application - Application stopped: io.ktor.server.application.Application@62a68bc
```

Here's the output from Gradle:

```
Skipping task ':compileTestJava' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
Resolve mutations for :testClasses (Thread[#1410,Execution worker,5,main]) started.
:testClasses (Thread[#1410,Execution worker,5,main]) started.

> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':testClasses' as it has no actions.
Resolve mutations for :test (Thread[#1413,Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:test (Thread[#1413,Execution worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
Gradle Test Executor 11 started executing tests.

> Task :test
Caching disabled for task ':test' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':test' is not up-to-date because:
  Output property 'binaryResultsDirectory' file /Users/xxxx/Projects/xxxx/development/xxxx/build/test-results/test/binary has been removed.
  Output property 'binaryResultsDirectory' file /Users/xxxx/Projects/xxxx/development/xxxx/build/test-results/test/binary/output.bin has been removed.
  Output property 'binaryResultsDirectory' file /Users/xxxx/Projects/xxxx/development/xxxx/build/test-results/test/binary/output.bin.idx has been removed.
  Output property 'binaryResultsDirectory' file /Users/xxxx/Projects/xxxx/development/xxxx/build/test-results/test/binary/results.bin has been removed.
  Output property 'reports.enabledReports.html.outputLocation' file /Users/xxxx/Projects/cashi/development/croms_api/build/reports/tests/test has been removed.
file or directory '/Users/xxxx/Projects/cashi/development/croms_api/build/classes/java/test', not found
Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 11'. Working directory: /Users/xxxx/Projects/xxxx/development/xxxx Command: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dorg.gradle.internal.worker.tmpdir=/Users/xxxx/Projects/xxxx/development/xxxx/build/tmp/test/work -Dorg.gradle.native=false @/Users/xxxx/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-worker-classpath12202243415355835399txt -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -ea worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 11'
Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 11'

ApplicationTest STANDARD_ERROR
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
    SLF4J: Found provider [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@44be0077]
    SLF4J: Found provider [org.slf4j.nop.NOPServiceProvider@2205a05d]
    SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual provider is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@44be0077]

ApplicationTest STANDARD_OUT
    TESTING IS READY TO BEGIN!
<============-> 92% EXECUTING [32s]
> :test > 0 tests completed
> :test > Executing test croms.ApplicationTest
```

I can't see anything indicating that @BeforeEach, @AfterEach or even @Test are executed.

When I add the ability to not run a server and alter the test to accordingly, the tests are run but I'd rather not have to mock the results and run the tests against a running server.

```
package croms

import croms.commons.helpers.getEnv
import croms.commons.plugins.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.config.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.cors.*

@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER")
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = getEnv("PORT", 5000) as Int, module = Application::module).start(wait = true)
}

@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") // Referenced in application.conf
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false, startServer: Boolean = true) {
    if (startServer) {

        embeddedServer(Netty, port = getEnv("PORT", 5000) as Int) {
            log.info("Configuring application...")
            configureApplication()
            log.info("Configuring logger...")
            configureLogger()
            log.info("Running database migration: ${getEnv("MIGRATE_DATABASE")}")
            databaseMigration()
            log.info("Configuring HTTP...")
            configureHTTP()
            log.info("Configuring security...")
            configureSecurity()
            log.info("Configuring response...")
            configureResponse()
            log.info("Configuring routes...")
            configureRoutes()
            log.info("Application started.")
        }.start(wait = true)
    } else {
        log.info("Server not started, running in test mode")
    }
}
```

And the corresponding test:

```
package croms
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.connector
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.config.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import kotlin.test.*

class ApplicationTest {
    
    @Test
    fun testRoot() {
            withTestApplication({ module(testing = true, startServer = false) }) {
            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/").apply {
                assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, response.status())
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testSerialsStatistics() {
            withTestApplication({ module(testing = true, startServer = false) }) {
            handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/v2/xxxx/serials-statistics").apply {
                assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
ApplicationTest > testRoot() PASSED

ApplicationTest > testSerialsStatistics() FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<200 OK> but was:<404 Not Found>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without starting the server?

Comment: Yes, a [mre] would help in this case

Comment: No. When I change Application.kt to have the option of not starting a server the tests are run: 

@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") // Referenced in application.conf
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false, startServer: Boolean = true) {
    if (startServer) {

        embeddedServer(Netty, port = getEnv("PORT", 5000) as Int) {
            log.info("Configuring application...")

        }.start(wait = true)
    } else {
        log.info("Server not started, running in test mode")
    }
}

`ApplicationTest > testRoot() PASSED`
`ApplicationTest > testSerials() FAILED`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with the messy way the Application.kt was creating the server, this seems to have resolved the problem and cleaned up the code:

```
package croms

import croms.commons.helpers.getEnv
import croms.commons.plugins.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.config.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.plugins.cors.*

fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") // Referenced in application.conf
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
        log.info("Configuring application...")
        configureApplication()
        log.info("Configuring logger...")
        configureLogger()
        log.info("Running database migration: ${getEnv("MIGRATE_DATABASE")}")
        databaseMigration()
        log.info("Configuring HTTP...")
        configureHTTP()
        log.info("Configuring security...")
        configureSecurity()
        log.info("Configuring response...")
        configureResponse()
        log.info("Configuring routes...")
        configureRoutes()
        log.info("Application started.")
}
```

ApplicationTest.kt

```
package croms
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.statement.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.connector
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.config.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class ApplicationTest {
    private lateinit var client: HttpClient

    @Test
    fun testRoot() = withTestApplication(Application::module) {
        val call = handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/")
        with(call) {
            Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
            val content = response.content
            val jsonNode = ObjectMapper().readTree(content)
            Assertions.assertEquals(false, jsonNode.get("status").asBoolean())
            Assertions.assertEquals(404, jsonNode.get("code").asInt())
            Assertions.assertEquals("الصفحة التي تبحث عنها غير موجودة", jsonNode.get("message").asText())
            Assertions.assertTrue(jsonNode.get("data").isObject)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testUnautherizedSerialsStatistics() = withTestApplication(Application::module) {
        val call = handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/v2/xxxx/serials-statistics")
        with(call) {
            Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
            val content = response.content
            val jsonNode = ObjectMapper().readTree(content)
             Assertions.assertEquals(401, jsonNode.get("code").asInt())
        }
    }   
}
```

I need to mop up the deprecated functions but the test case is running as expected and producing reports:

```
> Task :compileKotlin
w: file:///Users/husseinbadakhchani/Projects/cashi/development/croms_api/src/main/kotlin/croms/commons/helpers/httpclient/HttpServiceImpl.kt:47:13 'handleResponseException(suspend (cause: Throwable) -> Unit): Unit' is deprecated. Consider using `handleResponseExceptionWithRequest` instead

> Task :compileTestKotlin
w: file:///Users/husseinbadakhchani/Projects/cashi/development/croms_api/src/test/kotlin/croms/ApplicationTest.kt:22:22 'withTestApplication(Application.() -> Unit, TestApplicationEngine.() -> R): R' is deprecated. Please use new `testApplication` API: https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html#testing-api
w: file:///Users/husseinbadakhchani/Projects/cashi/development/croms_api/src/test/kotlin/croms/ApplicationTest.kt:36:47 'withTestApplication(Application.() -> Unit, TestApplicationEngine.() -> R): R' is deprecated. Please use new `testApplication` API: https://ktor.io/docs/migrating-2.html#testing-api

> Task :test

ApplicationTest > testRoot() PASSED

ApplicationTest > testUnautherizedSerialsStatistics() PASSED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
```